# how to capture the spaces in regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I want to capture the `195988_BQ` using a regular expression.

I have applied the regular expression, but it's not working because it has spaces in the response.

**applied** **product-name"
                                                value="(.+?)"**  it's not working

**Actual response:**
**product-name"
                                                value="195988_BQ"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `(\s+)` which will capture all spaces

```
  product-name"(\s+)value="(.+?)
```

But then get the **second** group by Template: `$2$`